# Bypass CORS policy using proxy.conf.json in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, cors

I'm trying to load a url in an iframe like

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;">
    <iframe src="api/depune-petitie/" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>
```

From my research I tried using proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://spv.anre.ro",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "/api": "/"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the first page loads, but when I try to navigate through the page, it no longer works because of `Refused to display 'https://spv.anre.ro/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'same origin'.`

And errors like

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://spv.anre.ro/PORTAL/start_page.html' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Can someone help me how I could bypass all urls that use https://spv.anre.ro and subpaths?

Comment: `Refused to display 'https://spv.anre.ro/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'same origin'` is easy, you're trying to display someone else's site in an iframe, and they have explicitly forbidden it ... you can do exactly nothing about that - similarly, you can't "bypass CORS", at least not directly in the browser - you would send a cleverly crafted request to *your server* that would make the request to the other persons site